# TypeScript Typings private registry

Tags: typescript, vpn, typescript-typings

I have some libraries in TypeScript inside a VPN environment and I would like them to benefit from `typings` tool so I can work with the typings defined for those libraries into new ones.

My thoughts came to the idea of a private typings registry, similar to private NPM repositories as artifactory provides, can this be done in a similar way?

Is there a way to publish my TypeScript libraries with their typings in a similar way that Angular1 or lodash have them in DefinitelyTyped repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not a repository, but you can install .d.ts files by specifying their location, like: `typings i --save jsonstream=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/JSONStream/JSONStream.d.ts`

(of course in your case the URL will be something internal to your vpn)

Comment: It definitely looked like a good option, but it didn't work :(

Our bitbucket server requires authorization to retrieve content from the repository so fetching like this would instead save the error HTML page

Comment: I got to workaround this by making the typings repo public inside our own VPN and referencing the raw content, works perfectly fine, thanks for the idea @erosb !